# Newbie: Invalid cross thread access with using busyindicator (silverlight and wcf service)

Tags: wcf, silverlight, multithreading, busyindicator

I have a problem with the busyindicator control of silverlight.
I have a datagrid (datagrid1) with its source set to a wcf service (client).
I would like to use the busyindicator control (bi) of silvelright toolkit when the datagrid loads itself.

But I have an "Invalid cross thread access" when I use "ThreadPool".

```
Sub LoadGrid()
        Dim caisse As Integer = ddl_caisse.SelectedValue
        Dim env As Integer = ddl_env.SelectedValue

        bi.IsBusy = True
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(state)
                                         AddHandler client.Get_PosteSPTCompleted, AddressOf client_Get_PosteSPTCompleted
                                         client.Get_PosteSPTAsync(caisse, env)
                                         Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                                    bi.IsBusy = False
                                                                End Sub)
                                     End Sub)
End Sub

Private Sub client_Get_PosteSPTCompleted(sender As Object, e As ServiceReference1.Get_PosteSPTCompletedEventArgs)
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = e.Result ' Here, Invalid cross thread access
End Sub
```

I know that the datagrid control doesn't exist in the "new thread", but how have to I make to avoid this error?

Thank you.

William

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First point: Why are you using the `ThreadPool`?

Using a `ThreadPool` would be a good idea if your service was synchronous, but your WCF service is asynchronous: it won't block your UI thread after being called using `Get_PosteSPTAsync`.

- Second point: there seems to be an issue with your `IsBusy` property. You're first setting it to `true`, then you starts an operation asynchronously, then you set it to `false` immediately. You should set it to false in the `Completed` handler.
- Third point: the `client_Get_PosteSPTCompleted` handler won't be executed in the same thread as the UI thread (even if you don't use the `ThreadPool`). That's why you'll have to use the dispatcher here so force using the UI thread.

Your `DataGrid1.ItemsSource = e.Result` must be modified to:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = e.Result     ' Fixes the UI thread issue
    bi.IsBusy = False     ' Sets busy as false AFTER completion (see point 2)
End Sub)
```

(note sure about the VB.Net syntax, but that's the idea)

- Last point: I don't know about the `client` object lifetime, but you're adding a new handler to the `Get_PosteSPTCompleted` each time you call `LoadGrid`. Maybe you could think of detaching handlers after use.

Comment: Super!! I have detached handler and use your code works fine. For the first point, could you help me?

Comment: @wnatahan For the first point, just remove the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` part. The code you executed in the threadpool will be executed in the current thread, but as the operation is async, it won't block the thread until completion.