# Silverlight WCF - Invalid cross thread Exception with busy indicator

Tags: vb.net, wcf, silverlight

I am implementing WCF in Silverlight.

At the time of calling WCF service in silverlight, I would like to show 'BusyIndicator' to user.

I came across implementing busyindicator at this [link](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2010/05/how-to-work-with-silverlight.html).

This is in C#. And I am developing project in vb.net.

Could not correctly convert this  to vb.net

```
busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
//busyIndicator.BusyContent = "Fetching Data...";

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
{
Thread.Sleep(3 * 1000);
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => busyIndicator.IsBusy = false);
}
```

While implementing above code in my requirement

The code in VB.Net is as follows:

```
busyIndicator.IsBusy = True
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(state)

      Dim s As New services.ServiceClient

      AddHandler s.confirmticketCompleted, AddressOf mcompleted
          s.confirmticketAsync()
           Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
       busyIndicator.IsBusy = False     
                    End Sub)
                    End Sub)



Sub mcompleted(sender As System.Object, e As services.confirmticketCompletedEventArgs)

        MessageBox.Show(e.Result)

    End Sub
```

Where services.serviceclient is WCF proxy with variable s

A completed event handler  needs to be used to get return value.

After implementing the code I am getting `'Invalid cross-thread access.' exception at
MessageBox.Show(e.Result)

My question is similar to [link available at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500957/newbie-invalid-cross-thread-access-with-using-busyindicator-silverlight-and-wc)

But I could not understand what Mr. Ken2k is saying.

Please guide and help me in solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `MessageBox.Show()` with the dispatcher `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(MessageBox.Show("BLAH")`  The service must be returning on a thread different to the UI thread, which is why you are getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

**Got it...**

I need to provide busyindicator.isbusy=false in completed function.

Remove ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem and Dispatcher.BeginInvoke altogether.

The final code looks like this:

```
    busyIndicator.IsBusy = True

        Dim s As New services.ServiceClient
        AddHandler s.confirmticketCompleted, AddressOf mcompleted
        s.confirmticketAsync()



Sub mcompleted(sender As System.Object, e As services.confirmticketCompletedEventArgs)

        Dim k As String = e.Result


        MessageBox.Show(k)


        busyIndicator.IsBusy = False

    End Sub
```

I really  thank ken2k for this. The link at stackoverflow is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500957/newbie-invalid-cross-thread-access-with-using-busyindicator-silverlight-and-wc).

Thanq can be treated as closed question.